# How to return new value from jEditable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jeditable

I can't seem to get the submitted value from my jEditable form to display on my website until I refresh the page. It does however update the MySQL database correctly. I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Could anyone explain how I use jEditable to update in place without refreshing the page?

**PHP ACTION PAGE**

```
if($_POST["issue_edit"]){
    mysql_query("UPDATE timeline SET comment='".$_POST["issue_edit"]."' WHERE ticket='".$_POST["id"]."' AND issue='1'");
    echo $_POST["issue_edit"];
    // header("location: ../?".$query."");
```

}

**MAIN PAGE**

```
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.edit<?php echo $ticket["id"]; ?>').editable('http://www.4dcreative.co.uk/support/tickets/action/index.php', { 
                        type        : 'textarea',
                        cancel      : 'Cancel',
                        submit      : 'OK',  
                        name        : 'issue_edit',
                        onblur      : 'ignore'
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <label>Issue:</label><p class="edit<?php echo $ticket["id"]; ?>" id="<?php echo $ticket["id"]; ?>"><?php 

            while($timeline_stub = mysql_fetch_array($timeline)) {

                if($timeline_stub["type"]=="issue"){
                    echo nl2br($timeline_stub["comment"]);
                }
            }

            ?></p>
```

Comment: "Show me the money!", ummm I meant code...

Comment: I've added the code above! Cheers mate.

Comment: Anyone know this. It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect whatever text was entered that's being passed as the `issue_edit` parameter to be lost ...

Maybe this was the behavior of a previous version(s) of Jeditable? In fact, I had a similar and yet somewhat-opposite problem where I had a number of fields where users can enter a number, but I wanted to update the number with a 'formatted' value (e.g. "1,000.00" instead of "1000").

To update the page without refreshing – and after the Jeditable plugin makes the request to the 'submit URL' specified – you need to supply a function to the `callback` option parameter in the call to the `editable` plugin function. Here's an example callback function from my own code:

```
function (result) {

    if (result.status == 'Success') {
        thisAmountElement.className += ' success';
        $(thisAmountElement).text(result.formattedAmount);
    }
    else
        thisAmountElement.className += ' danger';
}
```

The code that handles the request at the submit URL returns a JSON object with a `status` and `formattedAmount` property. [The `formattedAmount` property contains the new amount submitted by Jeditable, but formatted using the same server-side code that formats all of the other amounts on the page.]